# Are augmented creatures considered their previous type?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, racial-traits, character-templates

For the simplest example, take a vampire, whose type is undead (augmented humanoid). Is it affected by *hold person*?

If the augmented subtype doesn't cause a creature to have its other subtype as a "type", then what does the augmented subtype actually *do*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Really, augmented doesn’t *do* anything on its own. It just indicates the creature’s “mechanical history” so to speak. If you read [the description](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/typesSubtypes.htm#augmentedSubtype), the closest it ever comes to describing an *effect* is

> A creature with the augmented subtype usually has the traits of its current type, but the features of its original type.

That’s all augmented does: it suggests that it might have features usually more associated with the former type than the previous type. Since type changes are always the result of some specific effect—usually a template—ultimately the actual things that the creature keeps and loses are up to that effect, and not the augmented subtype.

That said, in a lot of cases, it can be wise to treat the augmented subtype as meeting *qualifications* for things. Not targeting effects—too many places note that type changes prevent that to believe it wouldn’t—but things like feats and prestige classes often make more sense when the augmented subtype can meet them as well as the original type. That has to be a DM ruling, though, on an *ad hoc* basis; it certainly isn’t in the official rules.

By the way, absolutely none of this matters for *hold person*—as that’s a mind-affecting spell, undead of any stripe are unaffected because all undead are immune to mind-affecting effects.